# Is there a function for this in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization, simplify

Consider the following example, for a user specified odd number of `N = 5` one should see the following output:

`A = [1 4 2 5 3];`

For `N = 7`:  `A = [1 5 2 6 3 7 4];`

In more general form for an odd number `N`:

`A = [1 ceil(N/2+1) 2 ceil(N/2+2) ... N ceil(N/2)];`

I went about the problem like this

```
A = zeros(1, N);
a1 = 1:ceil(N/2): a2 = ceil(N/2+1):N;
j = 1; k = 1; 

for i = 1:N
    if rem(i, 2) ~= 0
        A(i) = a1(j);
        j = j+1;
    else 
        A(i) = a2(k);
        k = k+1;
    end
end
```

I feel that there are better ways of coding the problem, optimisation and simplicity-wise. I would appreciate it if you could guide me toward what I am seeking.

Comment: There isn't much to optimize here. There me be a way to go backwards and forwards through the process at the same time so that you only have to loop through it N/2 instead of N times, but from an optimization point of view, that is not very significant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A one linear solution:

```
A([1:2:N, 2:2:N]) = 1:N;
```

It can be regarded as the combination of these index operations:

```
A(1:2:N) = 1:(N+1)/2;
A(2:2:N) = (N+3)/2:N;
```

Comment: Great solution! And it works for even `N` too